# Variable Amount of Generics in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics, tuples

In C++ you can create a tuple with a variable number of parameters. How would I implement something like this in Java without explicitly hard coding the amount of generics. I want to be able to do something like:

Tuple<Integer, Integer, String> t

but without forcing myself to use three items in a tuple.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [In Java, can I specify any amount of generic type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33569103/6395627).

Comment: Note that the use of Tuples is generally discouraged in Java (also in C++). Prefer a `record` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, that's not supported in Java.